# Using 'Am I' as a question

Tags: grammar, british-english

Can I use Am I as a question while talking to one other person. 
Examples:

Am I meeting you later?

Am I eating there?

Am I going to go?

In these examples I am questioning the other person. The inflection is on the Am I party if the question.  I'm not sure whether this is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

These are deleted forms usually querying what arrangements have already been made, rather than questions using 'be' as the copula ("Am I taller than Gerry?") This is made clear by the *ing*-forms after the subject, indicating that 'Am' is being used in its auxiliary capacity. The present continuous is used to denote (possible) future events.

"Am I meeting you later?" usually means "Have we made arrangements to meet later? [It's slipped my mind.]" Occasionally, it is used as a hedged form of "[So,] can we meet later?"

Emphasising the 'I' (Am **I** ...) has the implication that the previous sentence say spoken by the other person was "George, Harriet and Joan are meeting me later."

"Am **I** eating there?" is a shorter version of "Has it been arranged that I eat there too?"

"Am **I** going to go?" is improbable, except perhaps as a soliloquy. "Am **I** going?" again means "Have you made arrangements for me to go too?" / "Have arrangements been made for me to go too [I've forgotten]?" / "Can I go too? Pleeeese?" Deleted forms often have different possible progenitors.

Comment: This sums up my ideas on it's usuage. I think it is used more conversationally. Thank you

Comment: @user62965 It is perfectly grammatical English. (I think that answers your explicit question of 'Is this correct?'. In fact it is perfectly fine in formal English (not only conversational).

Comment: AFAIK (am i ..) usually used to ask y / n question.